# Swift tableview row color based from subtitle

Tags: swift, uitableview, date, row

I would like to change the color of the rows in my tableview to red.. if the date (subtitle) is older than 5 days from today. I tried something like: (example with the textfield color)

```
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Item
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name! + "-" + item.etage! + "-" + item.raum!
    let note = item.date
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(note!)"

    if note == "04.04.2016 20:31:55" {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {

    }


    return cell
}
```

and it works.. but only with the exact time (minutes, seconds).
How can i do this with compare only the day minus 5 days?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension of NSDate:

```
extension NSDate {
    func numberOfDaysRoundedUp(toDateTime : NSDate) -> Int {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: self, toDate: toDateTime, options: [])
        return abs(components.day)
    }

    func olderThanFiveDays(toDateTime : NSDate) -> Bool {
        return (numberOfDaysRoundedUp(toDateTime) > 5)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
// Today (4 April 2016 - 19:16:14)
let date : NSDate = NSDate()

// 1 April 2016 - 19:16:14
let aprilFirst : NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(1459538184))
// 1 March 2016 - 19:29:00
let marchFirst : NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(1456860540))

print(date.numberOfDaysRoundedUp(aprilFirst)) // 3
print(date.olderThanFiveDays(aprilFirst)) // False

print(date.numberOfDaysRoundedUp(marchFirst)) // 34
print(date.olderThanFiveDays(marchFirst)) // True
```

It might be a rough method but i think it is easy to understand and easy to change and fit your needs.

Comment: please never use `(60 * 60 * 24)` for date calculations. Days can be 23, 24 or 25 hours log — due to DST.

Comment: You are right for general cases, I did say it was a rough method but i will update accordingly so people will not copy this answer in the future